# Laravel: Access website from 2 different domains one of them through https and the other from http

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, http, https

I have a laravel website and i forced HTTPS from .htaccess and i access the website though https://leadersuae.net .. now i need to access same website from another domain that doesn't have SSL certificate and the domain http://leadersuae.ae
How can i achieve that from .htaccess file because when i open http://leadersuae.ae of course the website if forced to HTTPS already .. so i need to force HTTPS for the first domain and not force it for the other one

This is my current .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Force SSL
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I don't think it's about setting up separate virtual host because both domains will access one website and .htaccess file in it forces HTTPS .. i need it to be dynamic per domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this? It should check if the domain is equal to `leadersuae.ae` and if its not, force HTTPS.

```
# Check if domain is AE OR NET
<If "%{HTTP_HOST} != 'leadersuae\.ae'">
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</If>
```

For this to work, please make sure you are using apache 2.4+.

Comment: It didn't work .. when i access the .ae domain i get forced to https://leadersuae.ae/

Comment: Is that not right? If you're accessing the .ae domain do you not want it to go to the .ae domain without https?

Comment: yes exactly! i need the .net domain to keep in HTTPS and the .ae domain on HTTP

Comment: Ok, so what is it doing at the moment? Because your comment sounds like its working correctly.

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain correctly .. when i type leadersuae.ae in the browser it leads me to "HTTPS//:" https://leadersuae.ae/  which isn't what i need what i need it to open "HTTP//:" http://leadersuae.ae/

and of course leadersuae.net will be "HTTPS//:" https://leadersuae.net

Comment: Sure leadersuae.ae will take me to leadersuae.ae .. look our company's main domain is leadersuae.net and it has SSL certificate but the .net domain is blocked in Saudi Arabia so we bought a new domain leadersuae.ae which wont be blocked but we didn't get SSL certificate for this one .. so both domains will access the same website but the problem appeared with .htaccess file that was forcing HTTPS from the beginning

Comment: I've updated my answer to use an `if statement`. Please try it.

Comment: In fact when i added this if statement before or after the 2 lines that forces HTTPS it didn't work it just stopped leadersuae.net from working at all and leadersuae.ae still forced to HTTPS .. lastly i removed these 2 lines that forceing HTTPS and kept only your if statement but same result .. i would appreciate if you update your answer with full htacces code just to make sure to your answer correctly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177476/discussion-between-s-r-and-yasser-moussa).